# Separable extension iff $\Omega_{E/F}=0$?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

I know if $E/F$ is a finitely generated algebraic extension of fields, then $E/F$ is separable iff the Kahler differential $\Omega_{E/F}=0$.

**Question**: I wonder if we only assume that $E/F$ is algebraic without finitely generated, and  $\Omega_{E/F}=0$, then is $E/F$ separable?

**Edit**: [This question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1738516/zero-module-of-differentials-implies-finite-extension?noredirect=1&lq=1) doesn't solve my question, since the answer there uses the assumption that $E/F$ is finitely generated.

Comment: Can you remind us what $\Omega_{E/F}$ is?

Comment: @DietrichBurde Kahler differential

Comment: @Arthur There are two definitions in [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K%C3%A4hler_differential#K%C3%A4hler_differentials_for_schemes).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Zero module of differentials implies finite extension?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1738516/zero-module-of-differentials-implies-finite-extension) - Lemma 1.

Comment: @DietrichBurde. No. The answer in the question you refer uses the assumption that $E/F$ is finitely generated.

Comment: I don't assume that $E/F$ is finitely generated..

Comment: @DietrichBurde Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Kahler differentials commute with colimits, and any algebraic extension is the colimit of its finite subextensions (more generally, any field extension is the colimit of its finitely generated subextensions). Applying the result in the finite case, we have your desired result as the colimit of a diagram of zero modules is zero.